# How can I download my ADB Wallet using automation scripts?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I've created oci cli and terraform scripts to provision an autonomous database.
Is there a way to download the wallet also with terraform / oci cli ?
Or is this only possible via service console (web) ?

Answer (score 0):

After installing and configuring ocicli by following [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/cliconcepts.htm), you can use the "oci db autonomous-database generate-wallet" [command](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/oci-cli/3.1.1/oci_cli_docs/cmdref/db/autonomous-database/generate-wallet.html) to download the wallet.

```
oci db autonomous-database generate-wallet --autonomous-database-id ocid1.autonomousdwdatabase.oc1.phx.abyhqljt7jdqblkyzwhwufqjcbfrvs3behzr4eusjkcjc5xjtftbv --file wallet.zip --password Welcome1!
```